# Shorthand form of generics that can be undefined

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, syntactic-sugar

I know that it is possible to do somethink like this in TypeScript

```
variable: number | undefined;
variable?: number; // shorthand version
```

My question is if it is possible to do something similar when using generics, for example

```
observable$ = new Observable<number | undefined>(); // is there a shorthand way to write this?
observable$ = new Observable<number?>(); // not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid thats not possible. Only think that you can is make generic for that like `type Optional<T> = T | undefined` or create alias `type OptionalNumber = number | undefined;`.

And do `Observable<Optional<number>>` or `Observable<OptionalNumber>`. But in my opinion `Observable<number | undefined>` is more readable.